# how to make a particular axis which isn't linear or log?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axes

I want to replicate this axis (see picture) and I have a range of values from 1-10 - what format is this in and how can it be achieved in matplotlib?

[image]

Comment: How is that not a log axis? It's pretty clear that doubling the value adds 1 horizontal step. (If that isn't clear to you, notice that halfway to 10 is about 3-1/3, or `log(10, 2)`.)

Comment: Because the variable it is plotting is not log. It is logspaced but not actually *in* log if that makes sense.

Comment: The variable is generally not "in log". If you want to force things manually, you can transform the `x` values with log2 before plotting, and then use the `LogLocator` tick locator. But more simply, just use a log scale in the plot and it does this automatically.

Comment: by _in_ log you mean 'labeled as 10^x'?  Be careful to keep the _representation_ of data and the _labeling_ of data separate in your head.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(1, 11, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator([1, 3, 6, 10]))
ax.set_xlim(0, 11)
plt.show()
```

[image]